# jQuery: Possible to wait for $.get to finish loading before continuing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

The folowing script does not wait for $.get to finish loading the page before continuing with the loop:

```
$.each(data.songs, function(index, val) {
    $('#nowartist')
         .append('song starting');
    $.get("http://localhost/play.php", function(data){
         alert('done');
    });
});
```

data is a JSON object

Any ideas or comments will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost/play.php',
     success: function(data) {
          //callback
     }
});
```

That should do it.

[Old docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)

[2021 docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: Just so the OP is aware, from the link above:  "Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active."

Comment: this works but also gives this warning in my Chrome browser: ```pace.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.```. Apparently this is because of setting `async: false`. Any ideas of an alternative that would remove this warning?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want to potentially lock the browser, you could do it this way which just keeps chugging through songs until they are all processed.

```
function play_next(){
   var song = data.songs.shift(); // Removes the first song and stores it in song

   $('#nowartist').append('song starting');

   $.get("http://localhost/play.php", function(ret_data){
      alert('done');
      if(data.songs.length) play_next(); // Call next song if more songs exist;
   });
}
play_next(); // Start it off
```

Note, it does alter the `data.songs` array by removing items upon processing. If this is a problem, duplicate the array before starting so it removes elements from the duplicate array.

*On a side note, I am assuming you didn't paste all your code... right now it loads the same page for every song, but nothing from the `song` item is being used to alter the request in any way.*