# $.each - wait for jSON request before proceeding

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have an issue with the below code:

the jQuery.each is speeding on without waiting for the JSON request to finish. As a result, the 'thisVariationID' and 'thisOrderID' variables are being reset by the latest iteration of a loop before they can be used in the slower getJSON function.

Is there a way to make each iteration of the the .each wait until completion of the getJSON request and callback function before moving on to the next iteration?

```
$.each($('.checkStatus'), function(){
            thisVariationID = $(this).attr('data-id');
            thisOrderID = $(this).attr('id');
            $.getJSON(jsonURL+'?orderID='+thisOrderID+'&variationID='+thisVariationID+'&callback=?', function(data){
                if (data.response = 'success'){
                //show the tick. allow the booking to go through
                    $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
                    $('#tick'+thisVariationID).show();
                }else{
                //show the cross. Do not allow the booking to be made
                    $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
                    $('#cross'+thisVariationID).hide();
                    $('#unableToReserveError').slideDown();
                    //disable the form
                    $('#OrderForm_OrderForm input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: Have a look here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761417/jquery-possible-to-wait-for-get-to-finish-loading-before-continuing][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761417/jquery-possible-to-wait-for-get-to-finish-loading-before-continuing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things two change for a quick fix:

1. Use `var` before your variables to make them local instead of global. That way, you'll get new variable instances for each of your iterations. Always use `var` unless you really intend on polluting the global namespace:

   ```
       var thisVariationID = $(this).attr('data-id');
       var thisOrderID = $(this).attr('id');
   ```
2. Use `==` to compare instead of `=` ;)

   ```
       if (data.response == 'success'){
   ```

Your code will most likely start working as intended after fixing these issues that you seem to have overlooked. But, if you're willing to go with a more drastic change, you could also make use of [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

To execute a bunch of fetches in parallel:

```
var fetches = $('.checkStatus').map(function () {
    var thisVariationID = $(this).attr('data-id'),
        thisOrderID = $(this).attr('id');

    return $.getJSON(/* blah blah */);
});

fetches = $.when.apply($, fetches);

fetches.done(function () {
    // all parallel fetches done
});
```

To serialize fetches:

```
var fetching = $.when();

$('.checkStatus').each(function () {
    var thisVariationID = $(this).attr('data-id'),
        thisOrderID = $(this).attr('id');

    fetching = fetching.pipe(function () {
        return $.getJSON(/* blah blah */);
    });
});

fetching.done(function () {
    // last fetch done
});
```

Overkill? Perhaps. But it's flexible, and sometimes may be worth the syntactic sugar of having code that literally reads "when my fetches are done".

(Note: The above implementation is an optimistic implementation for illustration purposes only. In a real implementation you should also handle failures.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use either 
1). Non-async calls (as illustrated in the following code):

```
$.ajax({
    url:jsonURL, 
    dataType:'json', 
    data:{orderID:thisOrderID, variationID:thisVariationID},
    async:false,
    success:function()
    {
        // do stuff.
    }
```

2).  If you're using jsonp cross site, you'd need to chain your calls instead of using each.  Use each to build a data array, then start calling the json, with each iteration using the data from before in the callback.

---

Added:  For op clarification, a cross site implementation, which sets up a list of items to process and then processes them individually.

I've broken into mostly Plain Old Javascript, which is think is easier to read in this situation:

```
var items = [];
function setUp()
{
    items = [];  // clear in case this gets recalled.
    $('.checkStatus').each(function(idx, el){
         values.push({variationID:$(el).data('id'), orderID:$(el).attr('id')});
    }
    if (items.length > 0)
    {
        consume();
    }
}
function handleResponse(data)
{
    // do your data handling and formatting here.
    if (items.length >= 0) consume();
}
function consume()
{
    var thisOrder = items.pop();
    $.ajax({
        url:jsonURL, 
        dataType:'jsonp', 
        data:{orderID:thisOrder.orderID, variationID:thisOrder.variationID},
        async:false,
        success:handleResponse
    });
}
setUp();
```

Note that although these all sit in the global namespace a they stand, they can easily sit inside of a closure or function (ie, wrap the whole thing in a $(document).ready() ).

Comment: It is cross site. I'm not sure I follow your explanation of 2. If possible could you kindly provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to desactivate the async mechanisms.
Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/933718/1343096

Answer (score 0):

See my comment I dont know why it went there instead of answer.
Here its made synchronous, so it waits for a response.

[jQuery: Possible to wait for $.get to finish loading before continuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761417/jquery-possible-to-wait-for-get-to-finish-loading-before-continuing)